# Cannot resolve setContentView(int) and findViewById(int) API

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I am new to android development. I am creating the Activity which extends the Fragmentactivity. The compiler says that cannot resolve setContentView(int) and findViewById(int).

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
implements ActionBar.TabListener {

CollectionPageAdapter my_adapter;
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    my_adapter = new CollectionPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(my_adapter);
}
```

XML file:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/pager"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>

</FrameLayout>
```

I do not understand what is the issue here.

Please help me.

Comment: Did you create a layout file 'activity_main.xml' in the 'res/layout' folder? Then please show your xml file.

Comment: why dont you say, R- cannot be resolved!!

Comment: please paste exact line of error,

Comment: Added the activity_main.xml file.

Comment: can you remove the xmlns:android tag from the ViewPager view and then clean and rebuild your project

Answer (score -1):

you don't call `setContentView` in fragments, instead you need to return a `View`from `onCreateView`

try this

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                  ...... //code
         View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);     
         ListView mListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
         mListView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);

           //view 
            return rootView;
        }
```

please feel free to ask antthing, I hopw this could help you

Comment: But it is Activity not a Fragment.

Comment: Yes, I misundertood this, btw have you looked this example, I figure out you want to do this, [link](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html)